# How do you add debugging information to an executable .out file?

Tags: debugging

In a Linux system, I used the terminal to create an executable file of a .c file.

However, I now require to add debugging information to said executable file.
Any way to help me out here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to recompile the executable with the appropriate flag(s) - the basic compiler flag to add debug symbols with `gcc` and `g++` is `-g`:

```
   -g  Produce debugging information in the operating system's native
       format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF).  GDB can work with this
       debugging information.
```

If you're using the `clang` compiler there are some additional options:

```
   -g, -gline-tables-only, -gmodules
```

Read the relevant manual pages (`man gcc`, `man clang`) for more information.